# how to handle context for this specific java class in Android

Tags: android, class, this, android-context

The `deleteDatabase` method needs a context in order to work.  So in my class there is a context declared called `ourContext`.  This class does not extend any other class like 
Activity so I guess you could call it a helper class.

The only place in the class that uses context is the one method shown below that is called `deleteData`. and this calls the `deleteDatabase` method that needs a context to work.

```
ourContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Is it possible to not declare a context for the class in this situation?  Can I use `this` for the context?

```
public class PlayGame {

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

 public PlayGame(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

 public void deleteData(){
     ourContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Context is a class, you have to be derived from it to use this as a context.  I suggest making deleteData take a Context as a parameter.  I assume its going to be called from an Activity, Service, or something like a view that has a reference to a Context.